# Top-Down approach vs Bottom-up Approach?

Tags: database, relational-database, data-warehouse

Which Approach is best for making the databases of the different universities.
Top down or Bottom up
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The top-down method starts from the general and moves to the specific and the bottom-up is vice-versa.

In some cases top-down design can lead to unsatisfactory results because the analyst and end-users can miss something that is important and is necessary for the system.

To begin a bottom-up design, the system analyst will inspect all the interfaces that the system has, checking reports, screens, and forms.  The analyst will work backwards through the system to determine what data should be  stored in the database.

[Here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_object_top_down_bottom_up.htm) is the reference